# Paperclip: specify attachment fields in post_process callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :foo
  has_attached_file :bar
end
```

I'd like to specify a `before_post_process` callback that essentially skips post processing based on some condition, but *only for the `:bar` field*.

The docs indicate that I can add:

```
before_post_process :skip_for_audio
```

but this callback will run for both `:foo` and `:bar`.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Paperclip [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#events), you should be able to use `before_bar_post_process` callback and if you return `false` the post processing for bar will be halted:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :foo
    has_attached_file :bar

    before_bar_post_process check_bar_condition

    def check_bar_condition
        ...
        return false if #some_condition_fails
        ...
    end
end
```